# C# CMD argument to be executed

Tags: c#

*I am trying to make an argument with the following*

What i am trying to achieve is once i click on the 'button4', the dns should be flushed and a pop should appear. I am stuck on this. Any help would be appreciated.

````
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = "/c ipconfig / flushdns",
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                });
            }
            catch { }```
````

Comment: See the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands

Comment: Thanks! I think i've kind of sorted it but im just trying to get a pop up to appear once the command has been executed and completed :)

Comment: See this https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/720259/How-to-run-command-prompt-command-and-get-output-i and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59235057/4694757

Comment: You haven't stated what the problem is.

Comment: It's not much of a problem, i just wanted a pop up to appear once the cmd is executed once the button is clicked.

Comment: Try to add this `UseShellExecute = false` `RedirectStandardOuput = false` `CreateNoWindow = false` or as the answer mentioned above print the results because it runs in the background. Aso, use `Arguments = "/K ipconfig / flushdns"`.
Hope that solves the problem.

Comment: Fix typo. Replace this `"/c ipconfig / flushdns"` with `"/C ipconfig /flushdns"`, to upper case `/C`, and remove redundant space.

Comment: @i_thamary `/C` - execute and exit, `/K` - execute and stay. That's the difference.

Comment: Also consider to setup explicitly `UseShellExecute` and `CreateNoWindow` properties for `ProcessStartInfo`.